# How to use recursion for every two elements in the list

Tags: haskell

I have already written a function to get a certain number of the coordinates for a line between two points.

```
line :: Coord -> Coord -> [Coord]
line (xa,ya) (xb,yb) = ....
```

But I faced some diffculties when I am trying to use it to get all the coordinates for a polygon. The input I put is the coordinate of vertex.

```
polygon :: [Coord] -> [Coord]
polygon (p1:p2:ps) = line p1 p2 : polygon ps
```

When I run this polygon , I didnt get the result I wanted to obtain.
Can anyone provide some help for this ? I know how to do a recursion for adding one to every element in a list but I have no idea how to use recursion for two elements.

So if I gives a list vertex [p1,p2,p3,p4] 
the function should return [line p1 p2 : line p2 p3 : line p3 p4 :line p4 p1]
How to use recursion to come true this ?

thanks a lot.

Comment: All coordinates between two points, there are infinitely many points between any two points on the line... if your function truly attempts that, then you should not even worry about it getting to the polygon function, because it will take... a while :) ... Anyway, the quesiton is a bit hard to understand, add some code and intended output, will make it easier to actually help.

Comment: `line p1 p2 :: [Coord]` ; `(line p1 p2 : undefined) :: ......` ? `(line p1 p2 ++ undefined) :: ......` ?

Answer (score 2):

> So if I gives a list vertex `[p1, p2, p3, p4]` the function should return
>
> ```
> [line p1 p2 : line p2 p3 : line p3 p4 : line p4 p1]
> ```

You probably mean either

```
[line p1 p2, line p2 p3, line p3 p4, line p4 p1] :: [[Coord]]
```

or

```
line p1 p2 ++ line p2 p3 ++ line p3 p4 ++ line p4 p1 :: [Coord]
```

which is equivalent to

```
concat [line p1 p2, line p2 p3, line p3 p4, line p4 p1] :: [Coord]
```

What you're describing does not type-check: `[x : y : z]` is a list that consists of one list, `x : y : z`, where `z` is the tail. But if `line px py` is an element of this list, it can't also be the tail of that list. `[x, y, z]` could also be written `x : [y, z]` or `x : y : [z]` or `x : y : z : []`. The confusion here arises from using `x : ...` to construct lists with recursion, but lists of a fixed length most often look like `[x, y, z]`.

---

Since you're using each point twice; once as the first argument to `line`, and once as the second argument, you could use the following recursion pattern:

```
polygon :: [Coord] -> [Coord]
polygon (p1:p2:ps) = line p1 p2 ++ polygon (p2:ps)
polygon [pLast] = ???
polygon [] = []
```

In the second iteration, what used to be `p2` becomes `p1`, and so on.

You can evaluate this by hand to get the picture:

```
polygon (px : py : pz : [])
  ~> line px py ++ polygon (py : pz : [])
  ~> line px py ++ line py pz ++ polygon (pz : [])
  ~> line px py ++ line py pz ++ ???
```

Unfortunately, it seems that to connect the last coordinate to the first, you want to somehow write `line pLast pFirst`, but `pFirst` is not in scope. *Hint:* You can rewrite this function so that the first coordinate is available when you reach the end of the list, e.g. by making a nested helper function:

```
polygon :: [Coord] -> [Coord]
polygon [] = ...
polygon (pFirst:pRest) = ...
  where
    polygon' :: [Coord] -> [Coord]
    polygon' (p1:p2:ps) = ...
    polygon' [pLast] = ...
    polygon' [] = ...
```

That is one way to construct an explicitly recursive function that does it.

If you were going to use the standard library, another way could be:

```
import Data.List (concat, zipWith, tail, cycle)

polygon :: [Coord] -> [Coord]
polygon [] = []
polygon ps = concat (zipWith line ps (tail (cycle ps)))
```

Comment: "`[x, y, z]` could be also be written `x : [y, z]`" could more directly convey the intent. short name for an internal function, like `go`, could be less distracting.  YMMV for all points, of course.